# Hive - Select count(*) not working with Tez with but works with MR

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, tez

I have a Hive external table with parquet data.

When I run `select count(*) from table1`, it fails with Tez.

But when execution engine is changed to MR it works. Any idea why it's failing with Tez? I'm getting the following error with Tez:

> Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
>           at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380)
>           at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:257)
>           at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91)
>           at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:348)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>           at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:362)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) (state=08S01,code=1)

Comment: Were you able to get the resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `tez.tar.gz` file on hdfs. I think you might be miss this step.

make a `apps` folder on hdfs

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /hadoop/apps/tez/
```

put the `tez.tar.gz`file

```
hdfs dfs -put /usr/hadoop/tez/lib/tez.tar.gz /hadoop/apps/tez/
```

give the permission to that folder and tar

```
hdfs dfs -chown -R $HDFS_USER:$HADOOP_USER /hadoop
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 555 /hadoop/apps/tez
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 444 /hadoop/apps/tez/tez.tar.gz
```