# Hive cannot create table or count rows in dataset

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr, hue

I was using hive normally when suddenly I was no longer able to run "CREATE TABLE ..." or "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ..." inside the HUE plataform.

Whenever I try to run one of those type of querys the following error occurs:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing
>   statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380)
>   at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:257)
>   at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91)
>   at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:348)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1840)
>   at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:362)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Apparently this error only occurs to table that I tried to run the "CREATE TABLE ..." query. For instance, if I take one of the tables that is bugged delete and re create it I will be able to query it normally (though I won't be able to run the query table as it will bug the dataset again).
I can also run any of the queries from which I'm trying to create a new table as long as I don't select the create table part of it.

Besides recreating the table, I also tried to:

1. Create table on a different schema
2. Create table with different formats
3. Apply the corrections from [Hive - Select count(*) not working with Tez with but works with MR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503973/hive-select-count-not-working-with-tez-with-but-works-with-mr)
4. Change to MR instead of tez (the query never completes)
5. Running the query inside Putty --> It works fine there

I'm running Hive on through HUE on a AWS EMR

Thanks in advance